# Python * operator after a conditional statement?

Tags: python

I am looking at a hackerrank solution in python about converting to military time. But i do not understand one of the lines in the code. It reads:

`h = h % 12 + (p.upper() == 'PM') * 12`

I understand the first part where it gets the remainder, but I am not sure how the conditional statement after the plus sign does not throw an error

Comment: Booleans are integers too. Check it with `isinstance(True, int)`. Then check the values of `int(True)` and `int(False)` and you should see what's going on.

Comment: the conditional is in brackets and is executed first.  It evaluates to a boolean value which is treated as 0 or 1 for the multiply by 12. The addition gets evaluated last.

Comment: Ohhh now that makes a lot of sense. Completely forgot booleans are integers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional returns 0 or 1. If condition is true, then it adds 12 to the hour, else it adds 0

Answer (score 0):

This is treated as three separate operations,

`(p.upper() == 'PM')`
then
`* 12`
then
`h % 12`

As `(p.upper() == 'PM')` returns a boolean 1 or 0